# Inheritance of built in types. Where did the author obtain the 'self' in the for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

```
class ContactList(list):

    def search(self, name):
        matching_contacts = []

        for contact in self:
            if name in contact.name:
                matching_contacts.append(contact)
            return matching_contacts

class Contact:
    all_contacts = ContactList()

    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.all_contacts.append(self)

print([c.name for c in Contact.all_contacts.search('John')])
>>> 
['John A']
```

This is the class the author wrote. He creates a class which inherits from the built in type List. I have trouble understanding the for loop. Since the author uses a for loop i.e 'for contact in self' resulting in me thinking that self =[] is declared somewhere. The author does not explicitly write this which leads me to assume that in the parent class there is a def **init** method which provides the self = []. I am unsure if my understanding is correct or is there something else to this entirely that I am not seeing.

Also I do not understand where the author obtain contact.name in the if statement.

EDIT

I have added the full code. My search result also only produces 'John A' and should also include 'John B' I have no idea why this is not working.

Comment: Yes self is the list created when you pass in an iterable when you instantiate an instance, in the code there must be an iterable of instances of some class passed when the instance is created  that have a name attribute, which you have not provided. Any list method is available to any ContactList instance you create

Comment: Re the missing John B, the `search()` method's return statement is nested within the body of the for loop, hence the for loop will terminate after one iteration only. You need to deindent the return statement - check my answer below for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` refers to the actual *instance* of a `ContactList`. Since `ContactList` is a subclass of `list`, this effectively is a `list` and so `self` can be iterated over in a for loop as can a `list`.

You can see the list methods using `help(list)` whilst in the interpreter, or by reading the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) or [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Where did `contact.name` come from? In the `search()` method each element of the `ContactList` (accessed via `self`) is bound in turn to `contact` by the for loop, and this element contains an attribute named `name`. An example is a simple class `Contact`:

```
class Contact(object):
    def __init__(self, name, phone=None):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone

>>> contacts = ContactList([Contact('Me','555-1234'), Contact('You','555-4321'), Contact('Someone Else')])
>>> contacts.search('You')
[<__main__.Contact object at 0x7f258eab0fd0>]
>>> contacts.search('Nobody')
[]
>>> contacts.search('e')
[<__main__.Contact object at 0x7f258eab0f50>, <__main__.Contact object at 0x7f258eabe050>]    # 'Me' and "Someone Else'
```

---

Note that there is a bug in the `search()` method (or maybe it's an error introduced when posting the code here?)

```
return matching_contacts
```

is within the body of the for loop and will be executed on the first iteration of the loop. This means that the search will only check the first element of the contact list. The return statement should be deindented to the same level as the for loop like this:

```
class ContactList(list):
    def search(self, name):
        matching_contacts = []
        for contact in self:
            if name in contact.name:
                matching_contacts.append(contact)
        return matching_contacts
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python; bound methods are implicitly passed the instance as the first argument. By convention we usually call this `self`; but it *could* be anything you want really.

So `self` here refers to an instance of `ContactList` which happens to inherit from `list` (*but it could inherit from some other type/class and `self` would refer to that class instance*)

**Example:**

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def foo(foo, *args):
...             print "Hi I'm {0}! You called me with {1}".format(foo, args)
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.foo(1, 2, 3)
Hi I'm <__main__.Foo object at 0x7fe29f46b750>! You called me with (1, 2, 3)
```

In contrast; `@classmethod`(s) are passed the "class" as it's first argument whilst `@staticmethod`(s) are passed nothing and act as regular non-class functions as if you defined them with `def` outside of the class.

**Examples:**

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @classmethod
...     def foo(*args):
...             return args
...     @staticmethod
...     def bar(*args):
...             return args
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.foo(1, 2, 3)
(<class '__main__.Foo'>, 1, 2, 3)
>>> foo.bar(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

In methods the fist parameter (`self`) is always the instance itself. And as the class of this instance is a subclass of `list` you can use every method of `list` on `self`, `__iter__`, too.